# Dynamic creation of QML ObjectModel elements

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I'am trying to dynamically create bunch of QML ObjectModel elements such as simple rectangles and then show them in ListView. But when I build my application nothing is appear. Console log shows only the message: *"Created graphical object was not placed in the graphics scene"*. Is there any way to do it right with this approach, or anything else?

**UPD: code**

*main.qml*

```
import "imgRectsCreation.js" as ImgRectsCreationScript
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml.Models 2.1

Rectangle {
    id: root

    ObjectModel{
        id: itemModel
        Component.onCompleted: ImgRectsCreationScript.createImgRects();
    }

    ListView {
        id: view
        clip: true
        anchors { fill: root; bottomMargin: 30 }
        model: itemModel
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0; preferredHighlightEnd: 0
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        snapMode: ListView.SnapOneItem; flickDeceleration: 2000
        cacheBuffer: 200
    }

    Rectangle {
        width: root.width; height: 30
        x: 10
        y: 330
        color: "gray"

        Row {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            spacing: 20

            Repeater { // little points at the bottom
            model: itemModel.count

                Rectangle {
                    width: 5; height: 5
                    radius: 3
                    color: view.currentIndex == index ? "sandybrown" : "white"

                    MouseArea {
                        width: 20; height: 20
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        onClicked: view.currentIndex = index
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*imgRectsCreation.js*

```
var sprite;
var component;

function createImgRects() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("ImgRectSprite.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready)
        finishCreation();
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (component.status === Component.Ready) {
            sprite = component.createObject(itemModel, {"x": 10, "y": 10});
            if (sprite === null) {   // Error Handling
                console.log("Error creating object");
            }
        }
        else if (component.status === Component.Error) {   // Error Handling
            console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
        }
    }
}
```

*and finally - ImgRectSprite.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 100; height: 100;
    color: "red"
    Image {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        source: window.slotGetFileUrl()
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be really appreciated

Comment: @Polentino ok, here it is

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a big fan of component creation from JS code - i tend to put QML code in .qml files, and "heavy" (well it's JS afterall) code inside .js files - .

Have you tried to dynamically create qml objects using the [Loader](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick2-loader.html#details) object instead?

Comment: thanks for your advice, I'll try to do my task with it. Especially as I see a lot of interesting code snippets in it's documentation, but I'm afraid of it will not help, because I'm really newbie to QML and Qt Quick :)

Comment: Can you show me how to create, for example, 5 Rectangles with different images in them, using Loader?

Answer (score 0):

Well, okay, I've solved it by myself. But I'm not completely sure that it's a right decision.

1. I've decided to remove *ObjectModel* from my main.qml
2. ... and replace it with *ListModel*

   ```
   ListModel {
       id: dataModel

       dynamicRoles: true
       Component.onCompleted: {
           for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
           {
               append({ color: "orange" })
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. finally, I've added delegate to my *ListView*

   ```
    delegate: Rectangle {
       width: view.width
       height: view.height
       color: model.color

       Image {
           width: parent.width
           height: parent.height
           source: window.slotGetFileUrl() // includes logic to select images
       }
   ```
4. ???
5. PROFIT!

Thanks for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `itemModel` as a parent for dynamically created object with `null` or `undefined` value:

```
sprite = component.createObject(null, {"x": 10, "y": 10});
```